# Plugin broke the site and unable to login in admin panel

Tags: plugins

Need help!
When I activated the below plugin it broke my site styles and unable to login to the admin panel as well. I installed this plugin to add google adsense script below the header.

Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/

site: http://piacademy.co.uk

Please, someone, help me to fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: If you have FTP or SFTP access to your host, you can try removing the offending plugin by deleting its directory. It's probably at `{your web root}/wp-content/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers`. (Caveat: I'm not sure how a plugin would cause a database error, so that might not be the actual problem.)

Comment: Thank @PatJ for reply, yes I tried renaming the folder instead of deleting it, but no luck. Not sure what changes it did in the wp-config file, please do you have any other solution, in desperate need.

Comment: @Dinesh what does "no luck" mean? did it not rename the folder? ie : blocked you due to permissions? or the rename worked but did no fix your problem?

Comment: @Dinesh can you compare your current wp-config file to a backed up one? or even a fresh wp-config file from an installation?

Comment: @Dinesh have you edited the the wp-config file to turn on WP_DEBUG (set from "false" to "true") -- this should print the MySQL error to the screen so you can see what the database error is

Comment: Guys thanks for all your help, there was a problem with my digital ocean and was getting mysqld error(not plugin related) and this article helped me to restore the website.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysql-can-t-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysqld-sock-2